# Is “Bist du fertig?” offensive?

Tags: meaning-in-context, expression

I am wondering on the use and the meaning of the word *fertig* in this sentence:

> Bist du fertig?

In Italian a similar expression could be “Ma sei fuori/matto?” in the sense of “You are crazy!” In my personal opinion this expression can also be used as a joke in order to tease someone. I don’t take it as a personal offense.
I would really like to know what the usage and meaning of “Bist du fertig?”, is. Is it offensive in German?

Comment: Depends on context and on tone. If you're having a blazing row and ask "Bist du fertig?" it's kind of offensive. Other than that, it's not offensive at all. If your boss asks you if you finished your work, he'll uses these words.

Comment: Ok sorry I had to specify that I meant "fertig" in the sense of crazy and not finished.

Comment: "Fertig" does not have a definition that corresponds with "crazy".

Comment: Can it be that in Austria people tend to use it in this way?
In the sense of "du bist verrückt" or "spinnst du"?
Now I am really confused

Comment: Fertig can have the meaning of _exhausted_ (cf. _fix und fertig_), but the question, as such, never means anything other than _are you ready_.

Comment: @Em1 My boss would never say that though. Always ‘Sind Sie fertig?’ ;)

Comment: @E.V. We don't.

Comment: @Jan Fair enough. In IT you are often "per du", so that's why I don't use "sie" at work at all.

Comment: Yeah, academia, especially chemistry, especially with a more conservative supervisor … ;)

Answer (score 11):

I have never heard that phrase used that way and meant to be offensive. It would typically be used as a question when inquiring if somebody is finished, for example, when wondering if you can take their plate.

I have, however, seen the word "fertig" used in an offensive manner:

> Der Typ ist voll fertig.

This would mean something like

> That guy is totally wasted

So you might say that when you see a person that is in an exceptional state of drunkenness, for example.

*(Source: Native German speaker, lived in Germany until age 19, lived in US the last 9 years.)*

Comment: Minor data point of reminiscence: for some reason back in my youth, at my high school, we used "der/die ist voll fertig" in the sense of "they're an emo, oversensitive wreck" (before "emo" was a thing). Weird, I know.

Comment: @Marakai This probably connects to the second meaning of "fertig" as *exhausted* in German.

Comment: @tofro Heh, I wouldn't have a clue. Just one of those youth language things. I mean, we were **all** exhausted because high school life is **so** hard! ;)

Answer (score 5):

These kind of second meanings words acquire often due to slang as your Italian example of *finished* meaning *crazy* seldomly translate literally from language to language. See for example German *blau* meaning *drunk* which gave rise to a number of idiomatic expressions (e.g. *blau wie ein Veilchen*, blue as a violet) but which does not literally translate into any language I speak.

However, as stated by others, tone and situation can make the phrase mildly offensive — or perhaps only irritating? For example, if somebody is taking a lot of time on a trivial task, somebody else could ask them ‘bist du fertig?’, implying ‘get a move on!’ Saying that to a policeman or a judge in the wrong tone of voice may get you fined if either decides that it was more passive-aggressive than neutral.

The second meaning of *fertig*, *exhaused* may also give rise to the occasional mildly offensive statement, but nothing that is intrinsic of the words will make them offensive *per se*.

Comment: In fact, you could even call these false friends: blau means drunk, blue means sad.